# Why C# Console Application Stops Working?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-server-2016, scada

I wrote a console application that creates a socket and listen for incoming packets on a specific port, extract them and run some sql commands for each packet.
The packets are coming from over 400 devices (Data Loggers) over a private APN.
so basically this program is a TCP listener, note that there are a lotta data coming, devices send data every 5 minutes plus any kinda event that needs to be sent, more than 135000 per day to be more precise.

My problem is that after a while the program crashes without any errors (program stopped working error!). This happens once or twice a month. **now I wanna ask is there a way that I can reopen this console application after it crashes ?! or any other advice would be appreciated.**
I'm using windows server 2016

here's a bit of the code:

**program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

/*
* declaring some functions...
*/

// main method

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    /*
    * some date configuration and variable declaration codes...
    */

    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 9191);
    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

    serverSocket.Start();

    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Server Started @  " + ymd_out[0].ToString() + "-" + ymd_out[1].ToString() + "-" +
            ymd_out[2].ToString() + " " + m_hour + ":" + m_min + ":" + m_sec + " -> v4.4 Sakhaei 19.11.03");

    /*
    * database configuraion codes...
    */


    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            ip_address = clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray()[0];

            /*
            * some code to basically validate the sender...
            */

            handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
            client.startClient(clientSocket, 0, clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray()[0], !false);
            if (num_conn > 50)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                num_conn = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /*
            *  closing the port, and again openning it whenever an exception happens
            */
            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();

            serverSocket = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 9191);
            clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            serverSocket.Start();
        }
    }

    clientSocket.Close();
    serverSocket.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**hanldeClient.cs**

```
class handleClinet
{
    TcpClient clientSocket;

    private UInt32 crc_update(UInt32 crc, byte a)
    {
        /*
         * some code...
         */
    }
    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, int _pm, string _caption, bool _def)
    {
        /*
         * some boring code...
         */
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }
    bool crc_Check(UInt16 _low, UInt16 _high, int _size, byte[] _rab)
    {
        /*
         * some other boring code...
         */
    }

    public static int get_detail_id_keyfi(string ip, string stmt)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = null;
        int output = 0;
        try
        {
            /*
             * database query
             */
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n FAILED to establish connection: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static string update_keyfi(some parameters)
    {
        /*
         * some intert into db queries
         */
    }

    public static int get_detail_id_ipFiltered(string ip, string stmt)
    {
        /*
         * some code including a db query
         */
    }

    public static int get_type(int uid, string stmt)
    {
        /*
         * some code including a db query 
         */
    }

    public static string get_name(int uid, string stmt)
    {
        /*
         * some code including a db query 
         */
    }

    public static UInt16 check_pressure(int uid, float pressure, string stmt)
    {
        /*
         * some code including a db query 
         */
    }

    public static UInt16 check_deactive(int uid, string stmt)
    {
        /*
         * some code including a db query 
         */
    }

    public static UInt16 get_tur_chan(int uid, string stmt)
    {
        /*
         * some code including a db query 
         */
    }

    public static UInt16 get_prs_chan(int uid, string stmt)
    {
        /*
         * some code including a db query 
         */
    }

    public static UInt16 check_off(int uid, string stmt)
    {
        /*
         * some code including a db query 
         */
    }

    public static string send_to_db(a lotta parameters)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = null;
        string feedback = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            /*
             * something like 500 lines of code including some insert/update query 
             */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n FAILED to establish connection, let alone executing sql commands: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }


        return feedback;
    }

    static int[] gregorian_to_jalali(int gy, int gm, int gd, int[] @out)
    {
        /*
         * some code...
         */
    }

    private void doChat()
    {
        /*
         * some code...
         */ 

        while (clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, 2048);

                UInt16 station = System.BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytesFrom, 0);
                UInt16 function = System.BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytesFrom, 2);
                /*
                 * some other code like the above lines...
                 */ 
                if (crc_Check(The parameters))
                {
                    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("CRC_OK");
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();

                    if (point_type > 0)
                    {
                        /*
                         * something like 150 lines of boring code
                         */
                        networkStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("CRC_ERROR");
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
                    networkStream.Dispose();
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ip_address + " : CRC Error ");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);

                Console.WriteLine(this.CName + " >> " + ex.Message);
                if (!clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" >>  Client is disconected");
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient);
                break;
            }
        }
        clientSocket.Close();
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: Difficult to say what stops it, but perhaps a Windows Service is better qualified for this, and you can restart it automatically from the Windows Service configuration. And also writing some data in a log file could help you to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Any hint in the Windows Eventlog?

Comment: @Steve I log all exceptions in try/catch part, but there are no logs for this crash, windows service sounds very good! tnx

Comment: Sorry if I make a mistake, but are you sure in the other side, your socket is not closed by something other, maybe you must catch by `WebSocketException` and check why ? After this relaunch automatically the socket

Comment: @KlausGütter unfortunately not :(